# Database suggestion for small Java app

Tags: java, database

I am working on a project (team of 4) we will be creating an application that doctors can use to maintain their patients information such as vitals, weight, etc. We have decided on using Java and my question to you is what database would you suggest using? Someone on the team suggested text files, but I would still prefer to use a database since I do not have much experience with them.

I have heard MongoDB is good, but I heard that is mainly used for larger projects. So what would you suggest we use?

Comment: An embedded database could also be an option. Less hassle (unless you need networked access), but all the nice SQL features.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [sqllite](http://www.sqlite.org/) if it's something that will be stored locally. [sqllite4java](http://code.google.com/p/sqlite4java/) can be used as a java wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely use a database. You'll want to write queries and doing that against text files will find you re-inventing the wheel.

Try MySQL for relational data and Mongo is indeed good for document data.

Read up on the difference between documents (denormalized data) and relational data (normalized).

Mongo can definitely be used on a single server for a small project. It has a really strong community around it and it takes very little time to get up and running.

The most important decision is going to be *how* you store/model the data.

Answer (score 0):

Use a database is good choice!!!
if you decided on using Java develop the app, suggest you use java orm hibernate and mysql,
use orm, let you team feeling use sql and database is not complex!

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar in OODBMS and your tables are small consider to use [DB4o](http://www.db4o.com/DownloadNow.aspx). Relational Database, I would suggest [Apache Derby](http://db.apache.org/derby/derby_downloads.html). Both are light and very easy to use and smaller in size.